# How to multiply inerpolate unescaped value to static value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, angular2-template

Example:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-my-template">
   <p>Hello {{{data.name}}}</p>
</script>
```

In this case, 
I want to multiply data.name value with static value. Is this possible?
Like this :

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-my-template">
   <p>Hello {{{data.name}}} * 10</p>
</script>
```

Comment: `{{{` shouldnt be `{{` ?

Comment: And what do you want to achieve by multiplying name with an integer?

Comment: I want to multiply two integers number one came from the database and second, came from js {{{ }}}.Can you help me?

Comment: Is data.name storing a integer?

Comment: yes, is an integer?